# grails create a validate function for classes with @Validateable annotation

Tags: java, validation, grails, groovy

I'm trying to create a validation method, that will validate an object and re turn true if it is valid or will render an error and return false otherwise.

the thing is I want to pass objects from multiple class but all with @Validateable annotation.

```
 def Boolean validProjectAndPermission(Validateable obj){
    if(obj.validate())
     ...
```

But I get an error:

```
Message: No signature of method: dav.server.DataController.checkValidation() is applicable for argument types: (dav.server.widgets.PreviewWidgetCommand) values: [dav.server.widgets.PreviewWidgetCommand : (unsaved)]
Possible solutions: checkValidation(), checkValidation(grails.validation.Validateable).
```

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: Put the error message in your question!

Comment: the .validate() is underlined by intellij idea.

Comment: does it compile, run, work?  then intellij is wrong. it's not easy for an IDE to cope with dynamic language features like this. prepare to see more...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are passing a `Collection<PreviewWidgetCommand>` instead of `PreviewWidgetCommand`.